# Eclipse: Post build Command not found

Tags: c, eclipse

In Eclipse, I am getting a post build error when I convert my C elf file into an IMG file.

This is the error:

```
Building target: USBDebug.elf
Invoking: ARM Sourcery Windows GCC C Linker
arm-none-eabi-gcc  ./cyfx_gcc_startup.o ./cyfxtx.o ./cyfxusbdebug.o ./cyfxusbdscr.o    -T"C:\Program Files (x86)\Cypress\EZ-USB FX3 SDK\1.2\/firmware/common/fx3.ld" -nostartfiles -Wl,-Map,USBDebug.map -Wl,-d -Wl,--no-wchar-size-warning -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--entry,CyU3PFirmwareEntry "C:\Program Files (x86)\Cypress\EZ-USB FX3 SDK\1.2\\firmware\u3p_firmware\lib\fx3_debug\cyfxapi.a" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Cypress\EZ-USB FX3 SDK\1.2\\firmware\u3p_firmware\lib\fx3_debug\cyu3lpp.a" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Cypress\EZ-USB FX3 SDK\1.2\\firmware\u3p_firmware\lib\fx3_debug\cyu3threadx.a" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Cypress\EZ-USB FX3 SDK\1.2\\arm-none-eabi\lib\libc.a" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Cypress\EZ-USB FX3 SDK\1.2\\lib\gcc\arm-none-eabi\4.5.2\libgcc.a" -mcpu=arm926ej-s -mthumb-interwork -g -gdwarf-2 -o"USBDebug.elf"
**/usr/bin/sh: C:\Program Files (x86)\Cypress\EZ-USB FX3 SDK\1.2\util\elf2img\elf2img.exe: command not found
Finished building target: USBDebug.elf
cs-make[1]: [post-build] Error 127 (ignored)**

cs-make --no-print-directory post-build
Converting ELF to image (.img) format
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Cypress\EZ-USB FX3 SDK\1.2\\util\elf2img\elf2img.exe" -i USBDebug.elf -o USBDebug.img
```

It seems odd to me that /usr/bin/sh appears even though I am in windows.  I can go into the command prompt and type this in and it works perfectly

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Cypress\EZ-USB FX3 SDK\1.2\\util\elf2img\elf2img.exe" -i USBDebug.elf -o USBDebug.img
```

Would anybody know why I am getting command not found?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the spaces and parentheses in your path are not escaped correctly.

I was able to fix this on my setup by going to "C/C++ Build" -> "Settings" -> "Build Steps"
and changing the double quotes (") in the command to single quotes (').

More information about this problem can be found here http://www.cypress.com/?app=forum&id=167&rID=78767